# regarding the usage of rangebetween in Windows.Partition function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I run the following code script

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as func
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
tup = [(1, "a"), (1, "a"), (2, "a"), (1, "b"), (2, "b"), (3, "b")]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(tup, ["id", "category"])
df.show()
```

[image]

Then there has the following window partition, and the result is shown as following. I am confused on how this result was generated using the `rangebeween.` For instance, why the fourth row of `sum` column is `4`, how `rangeBetween(Window.currentRow, 1)` works to get this value of `4`. Moreover, according to Spark doc,
`Window.currentRow` is defined as `0`, why the code does not use `0` instead.

```
window = Window.partitionBy("category").orderBy("id").rangeBetween(Window.currentRow, 1)
df.withColumn("sum", func.sum("id").over(window)).show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Window.currentRow` and `0` should be equivalent. I guess it's just a matter of preference. As for why you're getting `4`, that's because the window spans between the values of `id` between the value of the current row and that value plus one, i.e. `1` (current row) and `2` (plus one). The three rows where `id` is `1` or `2` will be included in the window, so the sum gives 1+1+2 = 4.